# Tkinter mainloop blocking effect

Tags: python, loops, tkinter

I have a main tkinter window where the user selects some files, marks his options and whatever. On pressing the Run button,3 things should happen:

- the main window disappears
- the background procces starts to run WHILE
- a new window appears and starts to print information regarding the running process(in the example below things such as, b is 3, b is 5, b is 10, etc.

Is there any way to do this without using 2 threads?(if yes,how? i tried but i cannot figure out how to end the processes) one for the GUI and one from the process. As far as i know, tkinter mainloop has a blocking effect.
Any advice is highly appreciated.
The next code should be revealing- there is a class for each window.

```
import tkinter as Tk
import time

class Mainframe(object):


    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.root=parent
        self.root.title("Main frame")
        self.frame=Tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()

        btn=Tk.Button(self.frame,text="Run momma",command=self.RunButton)
        btn.pack()

     def Secondwindow(self):

        self.root.destroy()
        newWindow=Tk.Tk()
        window=Secondframe(newWindow)


    def process(self):

        b=0
        for a in range(0,20):
            b=a
            print (b)
            time.sleep(0.2)

    def RunButton(self):

        self.Secondwindow()
        self.process()


class Secondframe(object):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        self.root=parent
        self.root.title("Main frame")
        self.frame=Tk.Frame(parent)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.root.geometry("400x300")
        self.root.title("otherFrame")

if __name__=="__main__":

    root=Tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    app=Mainframe(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can kill one window and boot another (using `withdraw` and `Toplevel`, you should never call `Tk()` more than once), but why would you do that? Why don't you just update the first window?

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import threading

class Mainframe(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.frame = FirstFrame(self)
        self.frame.pack()

    def change(self, frame):
        self.frame.pack_forget() # delete currrent frame
        self.frame = frame(self)
        self.frame.pack() # make new frame

class FirstFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)

        master.title("Main frame")
        master.geometry("800x600")

        btn=tk.Button(self,text="Run momma",command=self.RunButton)
        btn.pack()

    def RunButton(self):
        self.master.change(SecondFrame)

class SecondFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        master.title("otherFrame")
        master.geometry("400x300")
        self.var = tk.StringVar(self)
        lbl = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.var)
        lbl.pack(anchor='w')
        btn = tk.Button(self, text="go back", command=lambda: master.change(FirstFrame))
        btn.pack()

        t = threading.Thread(target=self.process)
        t.start()


    def process(self):
        b=0
        for a in range(0,20):
            b=a
            print (b)
            self.var.set("Current value is {}".format(b))
            time.sleep(0.2)

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=Mainframe()
    app.mainloop()
```

Notice I still used threading. That's because you can't enter a blocking loop when you are using tkinter, since the GUI will lock up. All long computation needs to be integrated into the tkinter mainloop (usually using the `after` method) or it's own thread.

Comment: Brilliant!. Thx alot. I m very new to programming and dont know all the insides, for example why you should never call tk() more than once. I also looked into using the after method but i couldnt figure out how to make it run only once. Anyway, thx for the answer, it's going to help me a lot in understanding this :D